# Simple PHP script to JavaScript function used in a onSubmit attribute of a HTML form

Tags: javascript, php, html, onsubmit

I've been stuck in this for hours. I need to Submit a form ONLY if one of the inputs is equal to a PHP echo.

Simpliflying the script, it is something like this:

```
<head>
</head>

<body>

<?php 

$A = rand(0,10); 
$B = rand(0,10); 
$C = $A + $B;

?>

<script type="text/javascript">

function ValidateForm() { 
    if (form1.name.value == '') {alert ('Must say your name'); return false; }
    if (form1.result.value != <?php echo $C ?>) {alert ('Result must be Equal'); return false; }
return false;}

    else {return true;}

</script>


<form name="form1" method="post" action="Another.php" onSubmit="return ValidateForm();">

Name: <input type="Text" name="name" size="40">; <br>

Solve: <?php echo $A; ?> + <?php echo $B; ?>; 

<input type="number" name="result" min="0"/>

<input type="Submit" name="send" value="Send">

</form>
```

Well all this (simple version) saved in a .PHP file.

I know the JS script will run in a .HTML file but the PHP won't.

What can I do to make this work? I think I should take the PHP or the JS script to another file, but How do I connect all the files with each other?

---

WEll... it WORKS now... for some reason... this is the actual code: 
The idea was to make a very simple captcha for old people; the website will work for no more than 100 old people.

```
<?php

$A = rand(0,10);
$B = rand(0,10);
$C = $A+$B;
?>

<script type="text/javascript">

function ValidarFormulario() { // pon atención al atributo 'onSubmit'
    if (formula1.nombre.value == '') {alert ('Debe ingresar su nombre'); return false; }
    if (formula1.ciudad.value == '') {alert ('Debe ingresar su ciudad'); return false; }
    if (formula1.fono.value == '') {alert ('Debe ingresar su teléfono'); return false; }
    if (formula1.email.value == '') {alert ('Debe ingresar su e-Mail'); return false; }
    if (formula1.respuesta.value != <?php echo $C ?>) {alert('Result must be Equal'); return false; }

    else {return true;}

}


<form name="formula1" method="post" action="registro.php" onSubmit="return ValidarFormulario();">

// some form forms inputs here

  CAPTCHA: ¿Cuánto es <?php echo $A; ?> + <?php echo $B; ?>?



 Su respuesta: <input type="number" name="respuesta" min="0" max="20" size="2" />
```

For some reason it's working right now. At least I learn that JS works in a PHP file (Amateur level right here)

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: I usually validate form data with php: `if (empty($_POST["name"])) { echo "You need a name!" } else { $name = $_POST["name"]; }`

Comment: The bots will submit the form directly without javascript. 
I suggest to store the variables in session, and check in PHP.

Comment: lots of improvements in cod styles: use lowercase instead of camel case (e.g. `onSubmit`); separate JS from HTML / PHP codes; use lowercase variables, HTML attributes & file names; missing `<html>` tag and DOCTYPE

Answer (score 4):

Your JavaScript is not valid, Format the code properly and this is how it looks

```
function ValidateForm() {
    if (form1.name.value == '') {
        alert('Must say your name');
        return false;
    }
    if (form1.result.value != <?php echo $C ?>) {
        alert('Result must be Equal');
        return false;
    }
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

If you looked in the JavaScript Console you would see the error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token else

Fix the code, the function is closed early, and you have a random else and a random return. Proper formatting does wonders so you can see the structure.

```
function ValidateForm() {
    if (form1.name.value == '') {
        alert('Must say your name');
        return false;
    } else if (form1.result.value != <?php echo $C ?>) {
        alert('Result must be Equal');
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

There is an error in your conditional logic. Your JavaScript should be like this:

```
function ValidateForm() {
    if (form1.name.value == '') {
        alert('Must say your name');
        return false;
    }
    else if (form1.result.value != <?php echo $C ?>) {
        alert('Result must be Equal');
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a little something missing. Check and compare with the other answer given.

Comment: @epascarello did you just down vote me because I was missing that last bracket and the repost my answer with the bracket added? It's been a while since this happened so I may have forgotten, but that seems like a cheap move rather than just commenting on my post.